# Energy meter, automatic line frequency detection

Tags: power-meter

We are designing an Energy meter based on ADE7816, we put line frequency as a programmable parameter, which will be entered by the operator, Is there any way to automatically detect the frequency using this chip,

and what is the best way or best practice to do detect frequency of power line in general.

Looking forward to your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skimming the datasheet, it looks like there is a way to get the line frequency:

[image]

https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADE7816.pdf

Page 29.